# Do import library files contain information that can break my application on updates?

Tags: c++, dll

I'm using a dynamic-link library, so I don't need to recompile my main application each time. What I'm wondering is if the import library files contain information that could break my application.

If I'm compiling an updated version of my library and replace the dynamic-link library only, then could there be a mismatch between the import library and the dynamic-link library? Since the application still refers to the old import library that it was compiled/linked with.

Comment: Of course there could be. Imagine if in your first version you have a `int foo(int, int)` function and in second version you change it to `void foo(float, float, float*)`. It's under your responsibility to keep new version compatible with old one (unless you update everything else too). Of course you can deploy them side by side (so each app will see and use version it needs). BTW also DLLs need to be compiled...

Comment: So to say at the very least, import library files contain function signatures?

Comment: DLLs have function signature, but it doesn't means that your application refers to signature to call functions.

Comment: The path to DLL Hell is paved with good intentions.  Do consider what you are *really* asking: "can I deploy a DLL update without testing it?" .  No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is under your responsability to deploy a new dll backward compatible to the old one. If you have a `void foo (bool)` and the new dll implements void foo(bool,int), your application continue to call `foo(TRUE)`. This means you have to leave `void foo(bool)` implemented and create a new `void foo(bool,int)` that is called from `void foo(bool)` with a default/secure value for `int` parameter.